# The encoding 'GB2312' is not supported. in reading process with matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I tried to implement k means by MATLAB. However, when I use `csvread('Filename');` in my program. It reminds me the Warning `The encoding 'GB2312' is not supported.` and the program can't read the csv data. Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

```
data=csvread('ClusterSamples.csv');

plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'r+');
[m,n]=size(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The character encoding is not supported.

If you're using Mac or Linux you can use the iconv(1) tool.

```
cp ClusterSamples.csv ClusterSamples.csv.old && \
iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8  < ClusterSamples.csv.old > ClusterSamples.csv`
```

If not, you can use a text editor to change the character encoding and resave

Comment: Thank you. I should just switch to the file's path and input that command into terminal?

Comment: Sorry. Can you be more detailed?

Comment: If you by "switch to the file's path" mean "move (cd) to the directory containing that file", then yes.

Comment: More detailed about what?   Character encodings in general?, the iconv tool?, using a text editor to convert?

Comment: What is meaning of `&& \`? I'm sorry that I'm not familiar with terminal.

Comment: Can I just use `iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8 ClusterSamples.csv > ClusterNew.csv`?

Comment: `&&` means and, the second command will only be attempted if the first command succeeds.  You can probably write the conversion of the file to itself, I'm just afraid that there is a risk that the program could read its own output causing further output to be gibberish.  And keeping a backup is always a good idea.

Comment: I've done this and it keeps reminding me the same warning. How to deal with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126028/discussion-between-oskar-skog-and-coding-rabbit).